# A topological property of flat morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a faithfully flat morphism of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that the generic fiber of $f$ is smooth. Then there exists a non-empty Zariski open subset $U\subset Y$ such that the morphism $f\colon f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is smooth.

For a closed point $x\in X$ we denote by $B(x,\varepsilon)$ the open ball in $X$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x$ with respect to a fixed Kahler metric.

**Question.** Fix $x\in X$. Does there exist $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for any $\varepsilon \in (0,\varepsilon_0)$ the following is satisfied:

for any $z\in B(x,\varepsilon)\cap f^{-1}(U)$ the intersection $f^{-1}(f(z))\cap  B(x,\varepsilon)$ has Betti numbers independent of $z$ and $\varepsilon$?

Remarks. (1) If anything like that is true, the above Betti numbers should not depend on the Kahler metric for small $\varepsilon_0$.

(2) If $Y$ is a curve, then the question is known to have positive answer as it is a part of a topological approach to the construction of the vanishing cycle.

Comment: The Betti numbers are constant over $U$. Doesn't that imply what you want?

Comment: @Ariyan: the OP's question is (analytic) local on $X$ (not $Y$!). Without properness of the map, in general the Betti numbers are certainly not constant over $U$.

Comment: By the rank theorem (of real manifolds), on the smooth locus the map is locally given by some coordinate projection. Then the question becomes how the $\varepsilon$-balls behave with respect to projection. There are certainly open sets which do not have this property w.r.t. a coordinate projection, but the question is about (small!) metric balls. I think for $x \in U$ it might not be too bad, but when $x \not \in U$ this approach doesn't really help.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Whoops. You're right, I misread the question.